# Javafx, how to detect mouse position?

Tags: java, javafx

I create a blue rectangle using JavaFX.

Can I change the color of the rectangle to red when the mouse moves into the area covered by the blue rectangle, and back to blue when the mouse moves out of the rectangle?

The rectangle I created:

```
public class ColorfulRectangle extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, Color.WHITE);

    Rectangle rect1 = RectangleBuilder.create()
    .x(50)
    .y(50)
    .width(100)
    .height(100)
    .fill(Color.BLUE)
    .build();

    root.getChildren().add(rect1);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading a bit about [MouseEvents in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html).

As for your answer:

```
rect1.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
    rect1.setFill(Color.RED); 
}
});

rect1.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
    rect1.setFill(Color.BLUE); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mouse event handler to the appropriate JavaFX component in which you want to track the mouse location:

```
final Label myLabel = new Label("Mouse Location Monitor");
myLabel.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        String msg = "(x: " + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY() + ")";
        // do anything now.
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the mouse-event based solutions described in other answers, you can also do this with CSS. Create the `Rectangle` without specifying a fill, and add a style class to it. (Note that the `Builder` class you are using is deprecated.)
Add a stylesheet to the Scene.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, Color.WHITE);

    scene.getStylesheets().add("rectangle-hover.css");

    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
    rect1.getStyleClass().add("my-rectangle");

    root.getChildren().add(rect1);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Then define the style in an external file:

rectangle-hover.css:

```
.my-rectangle {
    -fx-fill: blue ;
}
.my-rectangle:hover {
    -fx-fill: red ;
}
```